# How to do this in makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here is my makefile :

```
BIN = ../mylib.a
CXX = g++5
CFLAGS  = -O2 -pipe -mtune=i686 -g
#################################



default:
    @echo 'Compiling socket' ;       $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c socket.c
    @echo 'Compiling fdwatch';       $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c fdwatch.c
    @echo 'Compiling signal' ;       $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c signal.c
    @echo 'Compiling heart'  ;       $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c heart.c

    @echo 'Create library static';    ar cru $(BIN) *.o
    @echo 'Compiling';                ranlib $(BIN)
    @echo 'Delete .obj files';        rm -f *.o
```

So this is my question..

Let's say I have 100 files. I want to compile them.

And I make changes in a particular file.
When I run the command make all those files from 0. And it rebuilds have to wait again until all those it rebuilds.

Now I want to ask how they can change that makefile above that to recompile just that file changed me.

Comment: While that's a functional makefile, it doesn't really take advantage of any of the actual features of make, such as dependencies and separate compilation. What documentation are you reading that suggested you build a makefile like that?

Comment: Hehe,I've never used GNU make.
I read the documentation gnu make.  Yes ie funtional this makefile :D For me works.

Comment: It requires only a small example, I want to not need to recompile all 100 files, only a small change. : D

Comment: The GNU Make documentation explains how to use makefiles. For example, see [A Simple Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile). It's probably worth your time to read this documentation.

Comment: I read the documentation, but fail to do what I said above. It is not necessary to recompile all files only for a certain change in a single file.

Comment: If I knew I not ask. so please. If you can help, answer. : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
.PHONY: all clean

BIN = ../mylib.a
CXX = g++5
CFLAGS  = -O2 -pipe -mtune=i686 -g
#################################

SOURCEFILES=socket.c fdwatch.c signal.c heart.c

all: $(BIN)

clean:
    @echo Delete .obj files
    @rm -f *.o

%.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling $*
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(BIN): $(SOURCEFILES:%.c=%.o)
    @echo Create static library
    @ar cru $(BIN) $^
    @echo Compiling
    @ranlib $(BIN)
```

?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. You can be reworked so as to save files .o  in a particular folder.